# Where does appctl (gcloud component) look for git access token or ssh keys?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, github-actions, google-cloud-sdk

I'm currently using `appctl` in GitHub Actions to deploy to GKE.

With some work I'm able to successfully install the gcloud sdk and appctl as well.
(Because the default GitHub runner installs cloud sdk from apt, I can't install separate components from that distribution)

I'm running the following to be able to initialize my config repo:

```
- name: 'Configuring ssh key'
      run: |-
        cd ${HOME}
        mkdir ${HOME}/.ssh
        gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="my-ssh-key" --project=${{secrets.GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}} > ${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa
        chmod 600 ${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa
        ssh-add ${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa

- run: export APPCTL_INTERACTIVE=false

    - name: 'Initializing git repo'
      run: |-
        appctl init my-app --app-config-repo=https://github.com/ORG/my-app-config
        #other operations....
        git add .
        git commit -m "Updated config for latest develop commit $GITHUB_SHA"
        git tag $(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
        git push origin --tags
```

The above works when initializing my repo and even tagging and pushing works as expected which leads me to believe that it's using my ssh key to authenticate to my config repo since it's private.

But when calling `appctl prepare dev` I get some good things at first:

```
Sync-up the latest Refs from remote ...
Generating kustomize artifacts...
Stash deployment git repo...
Writing release artifact to deployment repo...
Pushing the new git-commit to the deployment repo.
```

Then I run into this.

```
Error: unable to find personal token. Please consider setting the environment variable "APPCTL_INTERACTIVE" to be true
```

Now what's strange is that all the pushing etc works as expected. The only thing is that it seems `appctl` can't create a PR? It pushed the tags and everything to the config *and* deployment repos.

Is anyone else facing a similar issue? I'm getting everything I need as far as pushing tags etc but the job fails because of the access token. If my original ssh key works when checking out the config repo and even pushing tags and commits to the remotes what is the last step `appctl` is trying to do that requires an access token and where would I add that in a CI/CD pipeline?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of looking and trying different things I've solved my problem.

I've discovered that when `appctl` asks you for your GitHub access token (which it uses to create a Pull Request on your behalf) it stores it in the home directory under a file called `.appctlconfig`

So the location will be `~/.appctlconfig` and I discovered this by watching the filesystem on my Mac and just noticing what's being read/accessed.

The format of that file is (you guessed it) a K8s Kind

```
apiVersion: appctl.gke.io/v1beta1
creationTimestamp: null
github_access_token: my-access-token
kind: Config
```

My solution was to mimic that format and just write that to the correct path before I call `appctl prepare dev`

```
${{secrets.APPCTL_CONFIG}} > ${HOME}/.appctlconfig
```

`appctl` is happy with this and successfully creates a PR on my behalf.

Comment: Hey I'm glad that you managed to solve your issue. If there's no better answer [after 48h](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) you should accept your own.

Comment: Sure! I have about another 3 hours before I can accept my answer @Ajordat